# Axion production from vacuum realignment and the strong CP problem

Tags: standard-model, dark-matter, cp-violation, axion

I am trying to understand axions as a possible candidate for dark matter. My understanding of one of the mechanisms by which energy could up in the axion field is by an initial misalignment between the field angle $a$ and the equilibrium field $a^*$. Since the axion couples weakly to everything there are not many channels through which this energy could be dissipated, so we would expect $a$ to oscillate harmonically about $a^*$.

This idea confuses me because my understanding was that the relaxation of the axion to the potential minimum $a^*$ was the dynamical mechanism that restores strong CP invariance. If the axion field instead oscillates harmonically about the minimum forever, it seems like one would expect there would be local regions with the $a$ field living in some near the peak or trough of its oscillation period, where the gluons experience a significant nonzero effective $\theta$ term. My question is thus: why doesn't this model for axions as dark matter break their most appealing feature (restoration of strong CP symmetry)?

Comment: Similar questions can be asked about the Higgs field: does the Higgs field oscillate harmonically about the minimum forever? Does this mean that the Higgs-generated masses of the fundamental particles also oscillate forever? Well, this might explain why body weight experiences eternal cycle of ups and downs for folks on a diet.